# How to store regex results from an array into a non-multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following regex:

```
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^(\"|\\\) ]+/i';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($column7); ++$i)
    {
    preg_match_all($regex, $column7[$i], $matches[$i]);
    print_r($matches[$i]);
    }
```

Column 7 is an array made up of many different strings. I want to match all the urls and store them in a single array $matches such that I have all the matches from each element in a single array like the example below.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => https://domain.comf3aeaf
        [1] => https://ureasdjlkfjasldkf.com
        [2] => http://heelooo.com
        [3] => https://www.asdfasdfasd.com
        [4] => https://asdfafrgasrgas.com
        [5] => http://rgtfgsdagf.com
        [6] => http://asfgdfhgasdgafsd.com
        [7] => http://asdghdthgaterge.com
        [8] => https://asdgsdhdsthaerararrrr.com
        [9] => https://t.com
        [10] => http://abc.cmo

    )
```

When I `print_r($matches[$i])` it looks like I get a multidimensional array which just overwrites itself. How can I just get a one dimensional array with all the urls one after the other?

I hope that makes sense!

Actual Output I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     https://domain.comf3aeaf
            [1] => https://ureasdjlkfjasldkf.com
            [2] => http://heelooo.com
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.asdfasdfasd.com
            [1] => https://asdfafrgasrgas.com
            [2] => http://rgtfgsdagf.com
            [3] => http://asfgdfhgasdgafsd.com
            [4] => http://asdghdthgaterge.com
            )

    )
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://asdgsdhdsthaerararrrr.com
            [1] => https://t.com
            [2] => http://abc.cmo
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add up all elements you get in for loop to a new array - Something like -

```
$newArr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($column7); ++$i) {
  preg_match_all($regex, $column7[$i], $matches[$i]);
  $newArr = array_merge($newArr, $matches[$i][0]); // or try $newArr += $matches[$i][0];
}

print_r($newArr); //should be your required array
```

See [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)